# modprobe: FATAL: Module nf_conntrack_ipv4 not found in directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kubernetes, linux-kernel, ubuntu-20.04

TASK [kubernetes/node : Modprobe nf_conntrack_ipv4] *************************************************************************************
fatal: [node1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "modprobe: FATAL: Module nf_conntrack_ipv4 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-91-generic\n", "name": "nf_conntrack_ipv4", "params": "", "rc": 1, "state": "present", "stderr": "modprobe: FATAL: Module nf_conntrack_ipv4 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-91-generic\n", "stderr_lines": ["modprobe: FATAL: Module nf_conntrack_ipv4 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-91-generic"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
...ignoring
fatal: [node2]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "modprobe: FATAL: Module nf_conntrack_ipv4 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-91-generic\n", "name": "nf_conntrack_ipv4", "params": "", "rc": 1, "state": "present", "stderr": "modprobe: FATAL: Module nf_conntrack_ipv4 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-91-generic\n", "stderr_lines": ["modprobe: FATAL: Module nf_conntrack_ipv4 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-91-generic"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
...ignoring
fatal: [node3]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "modprobe: FATAL: Module nf_conntrack_ipv4 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-91-generic\n", "name": "nf_conntrack_ipv4", "params": "", "rc": 1, "state": "present", "stderr": "modprobe: FATAL: Module nf_conntrack_ipv4 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-91-generic\n", "stderr_lines": ["modprobe: FATAL: Module nf_conntrack_ipv4 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-91-generic"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

Answer (score 5):

https://cloudolife.com/2021/08/28/Kubernetes-K8S/Kubespray/Use-Kubespray-to-deploy-a-Production-Ready-Kubernetes-Cluster/

nf_conntrack_ipv4 havs been rename to nf_conntrack since Linux kernel 4.18+

Comment: +1 for deducing that the OP did have a question. -  Normally getting good answers requires a clear and useful question which ends in a question mark `?` and which is [well written](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) , [on-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) and contains sufficient details.